# RestRequest RequestBody instead of Params

Tags: rest-service, string

I am leveraging a webhook from a third party API (Mandrill) that sends me JSON, and have set up a Force.com public site with a RestResource to handle the incoming request. I've been noticing that if the request body gets too big (the JSON is all on a single parameter), it cuts off around ~10k characters (my current request has about ~80k). While this is definitely not the normal size of the payload, when an error occurs it adds subsequent values to the payload for the next retry, and that appears to how I got to this point.

What I'm mostly curious about is whether there is any way to force the use of RequestBody instead of Params. If I could leverage the Blob instead of a String, I shouldn't have the same issue (I tested it by POSTing a request with the same body, but without setting the Content-Type (in this case application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and I was able to see the entire request. From the documentation, it appears that if your request params are JSON, SF will deserialize it into a Map of Strings for you and clear out the RequestBody.

**UPDATE: Adding Sample Code**

The pertinent request headers:

```
POST /services/apexrest/Webhook HTTP/1.1
Host:  
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: 462817
Connection: close 
Accept: */*
```

Sample Data (extrapolate this to a bigger size, my actual data has sensitive information). The key is there is one parameter, and a lot of data within it (my actual values have about 15 fields per item):

```
events=[{"event":"test", "msg":"test"}, {"event":"test2", "msg":"test2"}, ...]
```

Code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Webhook/*')
global without sharing class RESTWebhook
{
    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet()
    {
        return 'Please use POST. No data saved.';
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        return PostHelper(req, res);
    }

    global static String PostHelper(RestRequest req, RestResponse res)
    {   
        try
        {
            System.debug('Body: ' + (req.requestBody != null ? req.requestBody.toString() : ''));
            System.debug('Params: ' + req.params);

            // here I can create a new custom records with the params.
            Webhook_Test__c wt = new Webhook_Test__c();
            wt.LongText__c = req.params.get('events');
            insert wt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            return e.getStackTraceString();
        }

        res.statusCode = 200;
        return 'Success';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per [RestRequest methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm), if the function accepts parameters, it will be deserialized into the provided parameters, otherwise it will be in `RestRequest.requestBody`. The solution, then, is to make sure your function takes no parameters.

> If the Apex method has no parameters, then Apex REST copies the HTTP
>   request body into the RestRequest.requestBody property. If there are
>   parameters, then Apex REST attempts to deserialize the data into those
>   parameters and the data won't be deserialized into the
>   RestRequest.requestBody property.

**Update 1**

---

I tested the behavior this morning, using the following test class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/demoRest')
global class RestDemo1 {
    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, req.requestBody.toString());
        return '';
    }
}
```

I used the following JavaScript in my browser to simulate the request:

```
(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), d = {}, i=50000;
    while(i--) d['d'+i] = i;
    d = JSON.stringify(d);
    xhr.open('POST','/services/apexrest/demoRest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+document.cookie.match(/sid=(.+?);/)[1]);
    xhr.send(d);
}())
```

The debug statement started off as:

```
{"d49999":49999,"d49998":49998,...}
```

Obviously, I can't post the entire debug statement here, as the payload was 727,781 characters long. My entire log was 730,252 bytes in size. Therefore, I have confirmed that the entire payload was transferring correctly, as I could visually review the string.

I then adjusted the loop from 50,000 to 200,000, resulting in a payload of 3,177,781 characters in length, and was able to confirm that the entire resource still loaded. In short, I'm not able to replicate any sort of problem with a simple 10,000 character payload, and in fact can read much larger payloads without a problem.

Finally, I adjusted the code to parse it using the standard JSON classes:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/demoRest')
global class RestDemo1 {
    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        System.debug(JSON.deserializeuntyped(req.requestbody.tostring()));
        return '';
    }
}
```

And was able to load a map with 50 elements that contained 1000 elements each, 678,268 characters of payload, using the following code:

```
(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), d = {}, i=50000, v = 1000, c = {};
    while(i--) { c[i] = i; if(i/v==Math.floor(i/v)) { d[i] = c; c = {}; } }
    d = JSON.stringify(d);
    xhr.open('POST','/services/apexrest/demoRest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+document.cookie.match(/sid=(.+?);/)[1]);
    xhr.send(d);
}())
```

Assuming your JSON is well-formed, your controller should load the request just fine. Since my example code is able to handle far greater numbers than what you're working with (8 times more!), the problem might be with some other error in your code.

---

**Update 2**
I wrote some new code to test this:

```
(function() {
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest(), b = [], c, d = 0, e;
    for(;d<10000;d++) {
        c = {}
        for(e = 0; e < 15; e++) {
            c['a'+e] = d+e;
        }
        b.push(c);
    }
    a.open('POST','/services/apexrest/phyrfox/demoRest');
    a.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    a.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+document.cookie.match(/sid=(.+?);/)[1]);
    a.send('q='+escape(JSON.stringify(b)));
}());
```

I honestly expected the system to place the data into the `responseBody` portion of the `RestRequest`, so I was unpleasantly surprised when it was empty and `params` was populated with one element (`q`) that contained the JSON. I re-checked the documentation to see what it had to say about `RestRequest`:

```
Name        Return Type             Description
params      Map <String, String>    Returns the parameters that are received by the request.
requestBody Blob                    Returns or sets the body of the request.
                                    If the Apex method has no parameters, then Apex REST
                                    copies the HTTP request body into the
                                    RestRequest.requestBody property. If there are parameters,
                                    then Apex REST attempts to deserialize the data into those
                                    parameters and the data won't be deserialized into the
                                    RestRequest.requestBody property.
```

The `requestBody` bit seems to suggest that the original question is legitimate, because it would suggest that there is a bug; as far as I am concerned, I would state that the documentation or the functionality should match in order to avoid calling this a bug.

Given this, however, the `params` map seems to be pretty clear about what it does: it maps named parameters into the map. We would expect this behavior in other languages, such as PHP's `$_REQUEST` global variable, because it is documented this way. While the description for `requestBody` is misleading (and clearly wrong, since there are other exceptions to the rule), the fact that it is being placed in `params` actually does make sense.

Consider Visualforce as logical extension of this. The view state parameter is submitted with postbacks, but clearly it must be treated as a parameter instead of request-body content. The reason why the view state isn't in the URL is two-fold: first, query parameters are more exposed, both to the user and to everyone else, and query parameters are limited in size compared to a request body.

The W3C recommendations for handling POST requests suggests that all parameters should be sent with the request body instead of the URL query-string method. The logical extension of this statement is that application/x-www-form-urlencoded payloads are query strings, which in turn are query string parameters. Since the payload is considered to be part of the query string, it is no longer content, but simply an extension of the action URL's query string. This is a perfectly sane way of handling/parsing the content, and one widely accepted on the Internet as a whole.

In any case, this actually is not a bug, but standard, expected behavior consistent with W3C recommendations and implemented practices around the web with regards to POST requests. You should either change your content type, or you should use the `params` map.

Finally, in regards to truncation of the data, I presume that your field is configured with a maximum length of ~10k characters. You can increase this to 32,000 or so, if you'd like, but you won't be able to capture 80k worth of text in a single field. You should consider using multiple long text area fields, or even better, storing the payload as an attachment or document, which won't suffer the same limitations on storage limits.

```
Webhook_Test__c wht = new Webhook_Test();
insert wht;
Attachment att = new Attachment(ParentId=wht.Id, ContentType='text/plain', Body=Blob.valueOf(req.params.get('events')));
insert att;
```

All of this being said, I would suggest that salesforce.com update their documentation on `requestBody` to note that form content types will transform the payload into the query string parameters.

Comment: My function is not set up to take parameters. What it is doing is if my request body was "[test: {a: 'b'}]", it would create a map in params where test was a key and "{a: 'b'}" was the value, provided the content-type of the request identified the parameters as such.

Comment: I'm going to look into this. Keep in mind that *Debug* statements may not show an entire string. Trying printing the size of the string and see what it is. You should be able to have strings up to at least 3MB in size (conceptually, up to about 36MB in Email contexts, but I haven't tested this), so the string size should be irrelevant. Try debugging the string's length instead of the string itself.

Comment: If you'd like me to help you sort this out, maybe we could have a chat or something. I'm able to load far bigger elements (see updated answer) without any errors.

Comment: Actually what I was doing (besides printing it out) was saving it to a long text area to validate. The issue is that if I just got the RequestBody, it would work fine, but due to the params being JSON and the content-type being set, SF is setting the params map and clearing out the requestBody, and the params map is having strings be truncated.

Comment: Can you post the specific code?

Comment: Just updated the answer, but in summary... this is logically expected behavior once you think about it. The documentation is actually incorrect, and the behavior *is* correct.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it is probably done on purpose. My field was actually 32,000 characters and was going to make more to handle the rest if I could get it to not truncate, but that doesn't appear to be happening. I filed a case with SF asking about the truncation, but for now I think this answer meets what we can do.

Comment: I wonder if your data is just somehow not properly encoded. I was able to successfully retrieve over 100k worth of text from params or from requestBody, without truncation (depending on the mode of operation, of course). Have you tried just viewing the debug logs instead of saving to a field? The logs should show the entire request. I know your data has sensitive information, but if I can meet a level of trust, you could send me a single request payload that fails via a PM or email so I could experiment with it in my dev org to see if it's replicable...

Comment: You know what is strange, I just had a WebEx with SF and its working now. I'm not sure what was actually causing it, considering I was able to repeat it last week with the same data that works this week (and headers), but perhaps something got fixed this week in the system.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me. salesforce.com issues hotfixes every week or two, things that they noticed in the logs that stood out as "unusual" or "broken" and things that internal QA finds after a release. So, looks like you're all good to go now.

Comment: @sfdcfox Did you try setting content type explicitly to application/json. I had similar issue. However, after setting content-type explicitly it worked for me.

Comment: @YsrShk Yes, the content type should be set correctly to avoid problems.